# Como efetuar um refresh no Dropdown automático do PrimeNg do Angular?

Tags: angular

Conseguir implementar um Dropdown num formulário de cadastro como podem perceber na figurar abaixo no campo **Estilo**;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se você parar para observar no canto direito do campo tem um icone, ao clicar no icone ele mostra um pequeno formulário que eu chamo de cadastro rápido de estilo veja a imagem abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não existe nada de errado nesse pequeno formulário no meio da tela, ele consegui cadastrar com sucesso, porém depois de cadastrar ele não inseri automatimante o novo registro cadastrado no Dropdown do campo **Estilo**

Veja como acontece, eu acabei de digitar **Criando um Teste**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conseguiu salvar com sucesso, porém não atualizou do Dropdown  automaticamente, veja;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Somente depois que eu fiz um refresh na pagina foi que ele mostrou o registro na lista no Dropdown  como podem ver abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de ao inserir o registro o Dropdown fosse atualizado automaticamente, eu não tenho ideia de como fazer isso, alguém poderia me dá uma ajuda?

aqui está o código responsável;

```
 import { CervejaService } from './../cerveja.service';
import { ToastyService } from 'ng2-toasty';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Cerveja, Estilo } from './../../core/model';
import { ErroHandlerService } from './../../core/erro-handler.service';
import { EstiloService } from './../../estilos/estilo.service';


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cevejas-cadastro',
  templateUrl: './cevejas-cadastro.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cevejas-cadastro.component.css']
})
export class CevejasCadastroComponent implements OnInit {

  estilos = [];
  cerveja = new Cerveja();
  estilo = new Estilo();

  origem: String = 'Nacional';

  sabor = [
    { label: 'Adocicada', value: 'ADOCICADA' },
    { label: 'Amarga', value: 'AMARGA' },
  ];

  display: Boolean = false;

  showDialog() {
      this.display = true;
  }

  hideDialog() {
      this.display = false;
  }

  constructor(
    private estiloService: EstiloService,
    private erroHandler: ErroHandlerService,
    private toasty: ToastyService,
    private cervejasService: CervejaService
   ) { }


  ngOnInit() {
   this.carregarEstilos();
  }

  salvar(form: FormControl) {
    this.cervejasService.adicionar(this.cerveja)
    .then(() => {
      this.toasty.success('Cerveja adicionado com sucesso!');
      form.reset();
      this.cerveja = new Cerveja();
    })
    .catch(erro => this.erroHandler.handle(erro));
   }

   salvarEstilos(form: FormControl) {
    this.estiloService.adicionar(this.estilo)
    .then(() => {
      this.toasty.success('Estilo adicionado com sucesso!');
      form.reset();
      this.estilo = new Estilo();
    })
    .catch(erro => this.erroHandler.handle(erro));
   }

  carregarEstilos() {
    return this.estiloService.listarTodas()
      .then(estilos => {
        this.estilos = estilos.map(c => ({ label: c.nome, value: c.codigo }));

      })
      .catch(erro => this.erroHandler.handle(erro));
  }
}
```

Esse trecho é responsável em carregar o  **Dropdown**

```
carregarEstilos() {
    return this.estiloService.listarTodas()
      .then(estilos => {
        this.estilos = estilos.map(c => ({ label: c.nome, value: c.codigo }));

      })
      .catch(erro => this.erroHandler.handle(erro));
  }
```

E esse é em salvar:

```
 salvarEstilos(form: FormControl) {
    this.estiloService.adicionar(this.estilo)
    .then(() => {
      this.toasty.success('Estilo adicionado com sucesso!');
      form.reset();
      this.estilo = new Estilo();
    })
    .catch(erro => this.erroHandler.handle(erro));
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela estrutura do seu código, basta chamar o método `carregarEstilos` dentro do método `salvarEstilos`

```
salvarEstilos(form: FormControl) {
    this.estiloService.adicionar(this.estilo)
    .then(() => {
      this.toasty.success('Estilo adicionado com sucesso!');
      form.reset();
      this.estilo = new Estilo();
      this.carregarEstilos(); // <------ Aqui
    })
    .catch(erro => this.erroHandler.handle(erro));
   }
```